# Run GUI Applications with Docker for Mac and X11 Binding

Tags: docker, x11, docker-for-mac

I am trying to run Docker containers that require a GUI with Docker for Mac. I followed [this guide](https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2016/07/31/docker-for-mac-and-gui-applications/), with macOS 10.12.3, Docker for Mac 17.03.0-ce, and XQuartz 2.7.11.

However, when I run `docker run -d --name firefox -e DISPLAY=$ip:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix jess/firefox`, nothing happens, and `docker logs` gives the following,

```
(firefox:1): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 16
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
```

Does anyone have experience with this issue? I have looked it up on the Internet and found no solution yet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Already tried this? https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2016/07/31/docker-for-mac-and-gui-applications/ I'm not able to try it at the moment

Comment: Yes. I mentioned that. @lorenzvth7